# The `.' operator cannot be applied to operand of type `method group'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have faced an error in unity scripting using C#

**The `.' operator cannot be applied to operand of type`method group'**

I write the following code in script and attach with one object for movement

**Code:**

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>.velocity += new Vector3 (0.1f, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

How i solve that error. I am using **Mono-develop**.

Comment: You're missing `()` in `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()`.

Comment: Thanks its working God Bless You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetComponent<Rigidbody>` is a method. You need to call it accordingly: `GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` (note the parens after the name).

So your example would look like this:

```
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity += new Vector3 (0.1f, 0, 0);
```